# Techniques for tiling and zooming of large bitmaps

Tags: android, maps, xamarin.android, tiles

I've been working on an android app that tries to accomplish the following:
 - Download large images from a service (about 4000px x 4000px)
 - display these images and let the user zoom/pan
 - draw overlays to show additional information

So far I have been somewhat successful by [loading a scaled down version](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) of the image and use that for panning and zooming, using [BitMapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html#decodeRegion%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) to load a high res representation of the current viewable area once the panning/zooming has stopped.

While this seems to work, I have realised that I'd need to put a lot of time in it to make everything smooth and stable, also I have got a hunch that a tile based approach will yield better performance. So my question is, can anyone point me to some lib or resource that will let me unload some of the work in an standing on the shoulders of giants approach :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late here, but I faced this problem and this answer might help others. I've recently developed an open source library that splits a large image into small tiles, showing only the visible ones. It also handles zoom/pan/double tap gestures. The source code and samples are available at https://github.com/diegocarloslima/ByakuGallery